# Error linking a certain function with the library

Tags: c++, templates

So I have the following function in point2D.h header file:

```
static VectorXY<T> create_x_y_vectors(const std::vector<Point2D<T>>& point_vector);
```

Then in the point2D.cpp file I use this function as follows:

```
template <typename T> 
static VectorXY<T> create_x_y_vectors(const std::vector<Point2D<T>>& point_vector)
{   

    VectorXY<T> xy_vec;
    size_t vec_length = point_vector.size();

    // Preallocate the vector size
    xy_vec.x.resize(vec_length);
    xy_vec.y.resize(vec_length);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < vec_length; ++i){

        xy_vec.x[i] = point_vector[i].x();
        xy_vec.y[i] = point_vector[i].y();

    }


    return xy_vec;

}
```

But when I compile my workspace I get the following error:

**undefined reference to `ASSplinePath::Point2D::create_x_y_vectors(std::vector, std::allocator > > const&)**

Also at the end of the cpp file following is included:

```
template class ASSplinePath::Point2D<float>;
template class ASSplinePath::Point2D<double>;
```

Here VectorXY is a struct which is defined in another header file. Therefore,
I have included this header file in both the point2D.h and point2D.cpp files.

After checking a few answers on stackoverflow and the error I did following:

```
template class std::vector<ASSplinePath::Point2D<double>>;
template class std::vector<ASSplinePath::Point2D<float>>;
```

But this still did not resolve any issue. Hence I am cluesless as to why there is an undefined reference to this function in a **.so file**

I dunno what I am missing. I have literally included all the header files from the library just to test if that eould work. But it didn't. Sorry if this is a silly mistake.

Thank You.

Comment: I would certainly remove the keyword `static` from your declaration and definition. What did you think that was doing?

Comment: I did try but it still gives the error

Comment: So I think you are trying to use explicit template instantiation, but that doesn't work with template functions like `create_x_y_vectors`. So I would just take the normal solution and put the function definition in the header file.

Comment: OK, I take back what I said above. I believe you can explicitly instantiate a template function. Try this in your cpp file `template VectorXY<double> create_x_y_vectors(const std::vector<Point2D<double>>& point_vector); template VectorXY<float> create_x_y_vectors(const std::vector<Point2D<float>>& point_vector);` See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/function-template-instantiation?view=vs-2019)

Comment: But @john If i include in the cpp file that what i mentioned in the question (after the sentence: included at the end of cpp file) then the compiler should understand right? that the template is used for double and float? Why cant we just right <Point2D<T>>   ?

Comment: Also @john When I try to include the lines you mentioned I got the following error:error: ‘create_x_y_vectors’ is not a template function
 template VectorXY<float> create_x_y_vectors(const std::vector<Point2D<float>>& point_vector);

Comment: @yashrunwal OK, I think you have a different problem. It looks like create_x_y_vectors is part of a class. You didn't make that clear. Could you post more from your header file so that it's clear what class it is part of.

Comment: It is a part of this class: template '<typename T> class Point2D : public Point<T, 2>{}' Inside these calsses there are a few constructors and then the create_x_y_vector function

Comment: @yashrunwal Yes, see answer below. Originally I did not realise that `create_x_y_vectors` was a static member function. I thought it was a global function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written your function definition incorrectly, it should be

```
template <typename T> 
VectorXY<T> ASSplinePath::Point2D<T>::create_x_y_vectors(const std::vector<Point2D<T>>& point_vector)
{
    ...
}
```

Your version defined a global function that was different from the function declared in the header file.

Comment: This works. Made a dumb mistake yet again! Sorry for that! Thank You.